# Set VS Code launch.json to use windows environment variables

Tags: visual-studio-code, javafx, environment-variables

I need to use the vmArgs config to run my app in JavaFX.
I want to use the path to JavaFX libs folder that is already in the windows path (or environment variables). But it doesn't work.

I've tried this:
"vmArgs": "--module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"

Then I've tried to change %PATH_TO_FX% to $env:PATH_TO_FX and "$env:PATH_TO_FX" but it didn't work too. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After days searching I've found the answer in the own Visual Studio Code documentation.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference
To use a environment variable the standard declaration is: ${env:Name_of_variable}